# Which WPF parts need Local Admin rights to work proberly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, admin-rights

I develop an application on WPF. I have recognized that some parts of the program do not work without Local Admin rights. On another question it is said that writing to event log was causing the need of LA rights. What other possible causes there are? I want to know these that I can find the cause of this problem easily.

Comment: I don't think there'll be anything specific to WPF. It will be things like the writing of log files to certain locations, or writing to the registry that are common to all applications.

Comment: Anybody else facing this problem? There are quite a many views on this question, but are any of you searching the answer to this question or just looking if you can answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There won't be anything specific to WPF as that's just the graphics side.

What it will be is common things like writing to the event log (as you've mentioned) or writing log files to certain locations on the harddrive or writing to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE area of the registry.

If you make sure that your writing to the user owned area of the disk and registry you should be OK.

Comment: We have a log4net logging system to a file. Maybe that'll be the possible cause. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with WPF. It is more based on the operating system and your login creditials. If your login credentials don't have permission to write to a file then your application will not be able to write to a file.

To work around this, you could add an app.manifest file to your .exe project. Once that is added, then you should open it up and change the `<requestedExecutionLevel />` node to have a level of highestAvailable. That should help you out.